# Volume to capture dropdown blank /Windows OS VM/

Tags: vmware-workstation, pxe-boot, wds

I have setup a 2008 R2 WDS server and I am trying to boot with capture image. /Both server and clients are VM on the Vmware workstation./
But when I PXE boot the VM and enter the windows deployment services image capture wizard, the volume to capture dropdown is blank :-(

[image]

Do I need to format drive of my PXE boot client? Or do I add the correct driver to the PE image so that I can see the volume to capture?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I've almost solved this problem. There may problem with that Sysprep wasn't completed successfully. So if dropdown lists blank, it may problem with sysprep

Answer (score 2):

This is a popular idea to test with that doesnt work. The VM drivers are not included in the standard boot image so it wont see the storage on the capture PCs C: drive.

If the sample desktop is physical, the test will likely work without change.